# Storing weekdays within a given date range in a scripting dictionary using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I provide two input params. startd and endd. These are dates in format mm/dd/yyyy.

I want to store the weekdays between this date range (start and end inclusive) into a dictionary. I have the below code.

I am getting **Compile error: ByRef argument type mismatch**

I do not know what type startd is being stored as. String perhaps? In the excel input sheet though I have formatted this as a Date dd/mm/yyyy.

I have two questions:

1. How do I type cast this `startd` to be able to use the `IsWeekend` function?
2. The original line I was provided with had `For n = startd To endd:  WDdict(n) = 1:  Next` . How to read this one liner syntax? I do not understand what is the `WDdict(n) = 1:` is doing here. Can someone explain, please?

   ```
   startd = Sheet1.Range("startd")
   ...
   ...    

   Dim WDdict As New Scripting.dictionary
   For n = startd To endd: iff IsWeekend(startd) = True, WDdict(n) = 1:  Next

   ....
   ....

   Public Function IsWeekend(InputDate As Date) As Boolean
   Select Case Weekday(InputDate)
       Case vbSaturday, vbSunday
           IsWeekend = True
       Case Else
           IsWeekend = False
   End Select
   End Function
   ```

Comment: Answer 1. Use CDate() to cast to a date format. Answer 2. ":" is a carriage return replacement used to have multiple code lines on one line - the one liner is actually a three line loop; break it down to the constituent lines to help error checking. Furthermore: IFF isn't an excel VBA function - it is actually IIF and should return true and false values from the function. Also dictionaries aren't arrays and should be referenced through keys and you should use the .Add member to store data. There isn't enough code here to help sort it out though

Comment: https://pastebin.com/mp3C2CBC I pasted half of the code that will give some context. Thank you! So, I tried CDate() and still getting ByRef error during compile time. I tried this fstartd = Cdate(startd) and then passed fstartd as the parameter inside the IsWeekday() function. Still getting the ByRef error :(

Comment: can you clear up what is going on with `For n = startd To endd`? Is that data type of `startd` and `endd` meant to be `Date`? Where did `endd` get set? Unless you specified the data type of start date somewhere in your `...`s, it is of type `Varient`. I imagine the ByRef error is happening because your function is expecting input param of `Date` type.

Answer (score 0):

So, I see a couple of issues here and I have some suggestions to make the code more clear and easy to troubleshoot.

1) use `Option Explicit` and force your variables to have strong types. This will help you know what is being passed around to your functions.

2) the for loop syntax you are using is a little confusing. I would use a more standard for block.

3) In your loop, you are always checking if `startd` is a weekend date. This will always return the same answer as `startd` is not changing as you loop. (`n` is what will change)

Taking some guesses at what your code is doing, I've come up with this as a solution:

```
Option Explicit
 Sub ClientCode()
    Dim startD As Date
    Dim endD As Date
    Dim dict As Dictionary
    Dim n As Date

    Set dict = New Dictionary
    startD = CDate(Sheet1.Range("startd"))
    endD = CDate(Sheet1.Range("endd"))

    For n = startD To endD
        If IsWeekend(n) Then
        dict(n) = 1
        End If
    Next n
End Sub

Public Function IsWeekend(InputDate As Date) As Boolean
Select Case Weekday(InputDate)
    Case vbSaturday, vbSunday
        IsWeekend = True
    Case Else
        IsWeekend = False
End Select
End Function
```

Where my sheet1 has the two named ranges that act like input cells. It will load up a dictionary with Key values that are weekend dates. The fact that you are just assigning the number `1` as the value in the dictionary might indicate that you could use a simple `VBA.Collection` object instead of a dictionary. But, perhaps your actual use of the dictionary is hidden in the `...`s of your example.